# What will happen if I reduce RF from 5 to 3 then decommission 2 of 5 nodes?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have a scylla cluster which has 5 nodes and my keyspace's replication factor is also 5. Now I want to remove 2 nodes from the cluster.

I plan to change the replication factor from 5 to 3, and decommission 2 nodes. Can I take this operation without a maintenance?

A safe and smooth online modification is what I expected ...

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: I think the separation between DBA Stack Exchange (which I wasn't even aware of until today, I must admit!) and Stackoverflow is quite artificial. There is a large number of questions on Scylla, Cassandra, DynamoDB, and so on, on stackoverflow, and by definition none of them are related to programming languages and many of them do not involve "coding".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the replica count doesn't require downtime. Decommissioning nodes doesn't require downtime either as long as there are sufficient replicas left in the ring plus there is sufficient capacity left to handle the application traffic.

The important thing to consider is that the cluster is repaired regularly (to make sure that the replicas are consistent) and that the nodes do not suffer from dropped mutations because it is an indication that nodes are overloaded.

If there isn't sufficient capacity BEFORE nodes are decommissioned, the situation will be even worse when there are less nodes because the capacity of the cluster will also drop so there will be a disruption to the normal operation of your application or worse, a service outage. Cheers!